# Spark do not resolve ivy specified repositories after upgrade form 2.2.1 to 2.3

Tags: apache-spark, ivy

We have spark configuration that uses *spark.jars.ivySettings* to customize jars resolution. 
Spark jobs run in environment without internet access, so we want to skip maven central calls and use our repositories.

In spark 2.2.1 everything was working fine, but when we upgraded to 2.3, repositories specified in ivy settings are ignored. As the result our jobs are failing due to missing dependencies.

Specifying our repos with new *spark.jars.repositories* makes it visible for spark, but does not change an order (so it will always first check maven central, which we cannot allow).

Is this some bug introduced in new version? Or I'm doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found where is the problem. So apparently the way of acquiring *spark.jars.ivySettings* has changed in 2.3. Now system properties are used for that:

```
sys.props.get("spark.jars.ivySettings")
```

This change is not followed by documentation update, and for me it seems like a bug.